# How to display checkboxes within HTML dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jsp, checkbox

I need to populate a drop down list (HTML `<select></select>`) with check boxes. I have tried to display such a list using a `<div></div>` tag and applying some styles in JSP page but it displays a list like a list box. Below is the code in JSP page along with Javascript that just alerts the list of languages which have been checked when the only button on the page is clicked.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Check box list</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function selectCheckBox()
    {
        var total="";
        for(var i=0; i < document.form.languages.length; i++)
        {
            if(document.form.languages[i].checked)
            {
                total +=document.form.languages[i].value + "\n";
            }
        }
        if(total=="")
        {
            alert("select checkboxes");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Selected Values are : \n"+total);
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="CheckBox.jsp">
        <div style="overflow: auto; width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #336699; padding-left: 5px">
            <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="English"> English<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="Hindi"> Hindi<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="Italian"> Italian<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="Chinese"> Chinese<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="Japanese"> Japanese<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="German"> German<br>
        </div>

        <br/><input type="button" name="goto" onClick="selectCheckBox()"value="Check">
    </form>
</body>
```

It just displays a list of languages as shown in the following snap shot.

[image]

What I need is to show this list of languages as a drop down (not as a list box). How can I do this?

Comment: Like, http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/ ?

Comment: @JoeTuskan You should really post this as the answer. Bhavesh, What Joe is saying with his comment is that plain old HTML can't do it...you have to employ some JavaScript wizardry...and some good people have already done most of the work and shared it with the world in the link Joe provided.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a link to a good library, http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/

With some nice test cases, http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/ddcl-tests.html.

In addition, here are some examples, http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html.

Comment: Good catch, unfortunatelly: "DDCL V1.4 is NOT compatible with jQuery 1.8"

Comment: @Sebastian Works fine with `jquery/1.10.2` and `jqueryui/1.10.3`. http://jsbin.com/OrEqUfI/2/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm not really late :)

Check this out: http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown