# Jquery Multiselect Drop-Down for filters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Html + js +jquery

How to implement Jquery Multiselect Drop-Down for filters ?

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#id").multiselect({
      header: 'ABC',
      noneSelectedText: 'ABC',
      selectedText: 'abc',
    }).select2; 
  });

</script>
```

Comment: its not really clear what u trying to implement...

Comment: This is fine Only. but i Forgot to add multiple => true at select box....Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few jquery dropdown check list plugins available on net -

1. https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select
2. http://jautochecklist.googlecode.com/svn/doc/index.html
3. http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/
4. http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/
5. https://github.com/scottwb/jquery.ui.dropdownchecklist
6. https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can use check box input in your drop down selection directly in your HTML. But if you want to make the selection multiple then you can do it by below code.

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-2">
   <select class="form-control" name="ms" multiple>
      <option>Type</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something jQuery does on its own ... There's an old project you could look at, based on jQuery 1.7, but this isn't maintained. However, it's open-source, so you could look at the code to see if there are ideas you can borrow to work with a newer version of jQuery.

https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/

Comment: This is fine Only. but i Forgot to add multiple => true at select box....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a good library, http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/

With some nice test cases, http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/ddcl-tests.html.

In addition, here are some examples, http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html.

From: [How to display checkboxes within HTML dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436488/how-to-display-checkboxes-within-html-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget.

Check these [demos](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/)